# How to evaluate clusters formed by DBSCAN clustering algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have formed my custers using DBSCAN. Now in case of KMeans I am aware that we use elbow method to get the value of K and we can use silhoutte score and plots either to determine the value of K or to evaluate K that was earlier derived from elbow method. What can be used other than Silhoutte score in case of DBSCAN?

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
object=DBSCAN(eps=5, min_samples=4)
model=object.fit(df_ml)

labels=model.labels_

#Silhoutte score to evaluate clusters
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
print(silhouette_score(df_ml, labels))
```

Is there any evaluation parameter other than this?

Comment: Hi, your question is focused on stats and ML, not programming and debugging. That makes it a better fit for our sister site [stats.SE]. I encourage you to post there instead of here, where it's off-topic.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Since it concerns specific implementation, I think it does not violate the SO guidelines.

Comment: I don't read it as concerning specific implementations. It's asking "what are the unsupervised clustering evaluation measures that exist?" That is: "Is there any [unsupervised clustering evaluation measure] other than [silhouette score]?"